# Do not return the capture "subgroups" in `gregexpr`

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of regexes that I would like to apply on a string, so that I can see which regex match the string. I thought about collapsing these separate regexes into a single one and then using capture groups to know which regex match the string. For example, instead of doing `grepl("a", "foo")` and then `grepl("b", "foo")`, I can do `gregexpr("(a)|(b)", foo)` and then use the `capture.start` attribute to know which regex match.

In the example below, I have two regexes (`"^a"` and `"cyprus"`) and one string to match (`"Cyprus"`). This works fine if I don’t already have groups in the original regexes:

```r
x <- gregexpr("(^a)|(cyprus)", "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)[[1]]
attr(x, "capture.start")
#>         
#> [1,] 0 1
```

Suppose now that I already had a group in the first regex, so that it’s not `"^a"` anymore but `"^a(b|a)"` instead. Then I get more groups than I'd like:

```r
x <- gregexpr("(^a(b|a))|(cyprus)", "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)[[1]]
attr(x, "capture.start")
#>           
#> [1,] 0 0 1
```

In the case above, it returns 3 groups because the first group contains two “subgroups”. I’d like to only have the results for the “top groups”, not the “subgroups”, so that the output above is `0 1` only. Is there a way to do that?

I’m looking for a solution in *base R only*, not using `stringr`/`stringi`.

---

**Edit:** following @user2554330's answer, I generate a random id for each regex. However, I have an error when the number of regex is larger than 127:

```r
append_unique_id <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    x[i] <- paste0("<", paste(sample(letters, 10), collapse = ""), ">", x[i])
  }
  x
}

list_regexes <- sample(letters, 128, TRUE) # <<<<<<<<<<< change this to 
                                           #             127 and it works
regex2 <- append_unique_id(list_regexes)
regex2 <- paste0("(?", regex2, ")")
regex2 <- paste(regex2, collapse = "|")

out <- gregexpr(regex2, "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> Error in gregexpr(regex2, "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE): attempt to set index -129/128 in SET_STRING_ELT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a lot more complex than simply using `sapply` on your vector of regexes. It does all that you want in a single line of code. In addition, you won't hit any limits on the number of regular expressions required and you don't need to cajole all your regexes into a single pattern.

```r
sapply(c("^a(b|a)", "cyprus"), grepl, x = 'cyprus', ignore.case = TRUE)
#> ^a(b|a)  cyprus 
#>   FALSE    TRUE
```

Comment: Yes, this is much simpler. However, that's exactly what I want to avoid because running `grepl()` separately on dozens or hundreds of regexes is much slower than running a single `gregexpr()` and extracting the groups.

Comment: @bretauv are you sure? I get a quicker benchmarks for `sapply`, and the difference gets larger the more groups I add. Are you able to post a realistic example for benchmarking?

Comment: Here's one: https://github.com/etiennebacher/example_gregexpr_SO. It's not minimal but it shows a big difference in timing

Comment: @bretauv - the difference in timing is due to the unnecessary use of nested sapply calls.  You don't need to iterate over `c(levels(sourcefctr), NA)` and inside that call iterate over `dict[[origin]]`.  Iterate over just `dict[[origin]]` and let grepl be vectorized on `c(levels(sourcefctr), NA)`.  Then you can use `colSums(x) > 0 ` on the resulting matrix.  Allan's suggestion is correct - in an apples to apples comparison it is significantly faster.

Answer (score 5):

You could use "named capture".  Just apply names to the top level groups, but not any of the nested groups.  For example,

```r
gregexpr("(?<first>^a(b|a))|(?<second>cyprus)", "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> attr(,"match.length")
#> [1] 6
#> attr(,"index.type")
#> [1] "chars"
#> attr(,"useBytes")
#> [1] TRUE
#> attr(,"capture.start")
#>      first   second
#> [1,]     0 0      1
#> attr(,"capture.length")
#>      first   second
#> [1,]     0 0      6
#> attr(,"capture.names")
#> [1] "first"  ""       "second"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Depending on what you want to do with the results, you could index by names, or delete any unnamed results, e.g.

```r
x <- gregexpr("(?<first>^a(b|a))|(?<second>cyprus)", "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)[[1]]
starts <- attr(x, "capture.start")
starts <- starts[nchar(dimnames(starts)[[2]]) > 0]
starts
#> [1] 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That seems to work in this simple case with 2 regexes. Since I have a longer list of regexes, I tried to append random IDs to each one. This seems to work until 124 regexes but then I get an error `Error in gregexpr(regex2, "Cyprus", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) : attempt to set index -129/128 in SET_STRING_ELT`. Do you know if there's a limit to the number of named captures that a regex can contain?

Comment: I' ve added an edit in my post with more details about this error

Comment: I don't see any documentation of that.  It looks like a bug in the R interface to the PCRE library:  it is working on some bytes as signed values when they should be treated as unsigned.

Comment: I've located the problematic line in the R source:  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/57d15d68235dd9bcfaa51fce83aaa71163a020e1/src/main/grep.c#L3079  If you typecast the `entry[0]` and `entry[1]` values to `unsigned char` (or some alias of that) it works.  There will still be a limit of 65535 on the number of capture groups, because PCRE uses a 16 bit field to hold the group number.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for going the extra mile. I'm going to talk about this in the r-devel mailing list to see if it's worth opening an issue in R-core (unless you want to do it yourself?)

Comment: I see that someone (you maybe) just reported this to R-devel, so hopefully this will be fixed in a later version. I won't accept this answer for now since it's not fixed yet

Comment: The report: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2023-September/082848.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of regexes, and you want to see if each of them matches a given subject, right? In that case, you need to use grepl + for loop or sapply, because gregexpr + a single regex with capture group alternates does not do the same thing. Alternation makes the regex engine consume the first alternate that matches, then stop trying to match the other alternates, after it has found the first match. For example see below, where both regex match, but gregexpr rightly says there is only a match for the first capture group, and grepl rightly says that each regex does match the subject.

```
> gregexpr("(s)|(sub)", "subject", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"capture.start")
        
[1,] 1 0
attr(,"capture.length")
        
[1,] 1 0
attr(,"capture.names")
[1] "" ""

> sapply(c("s","sub"), grepl, "subject")
   s  sub 
TRUE TRUE
```